# What's the best JQuery plugin for form validation that works well with Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, jquery-ui

Any ideas? I want to do form validation via ajax.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in regards to your needs? Do you need a forms validation plugin or a ajax forms plugin?

Comment: Any plugin will work. There is nothing specific to Django.

Comment: How Grillz answer become the accepted answer... it doesn't address validation with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say specifically for Django, but The jquery Form plugin is the best one I've found in general.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Doing a quick google only brings up one issue between the two - [Issue with Django form when submitted using jQuery form plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882526/issue-with-django-form-when-submitted-using-jquery-form-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation - only js.

Or you can use http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-forms/ with django

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet myself, but I've seen Vanadium in action on one site, and I have it on my list to investigate for my own projects: http://vanadiumjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look at bValidator: http://code.google.com/p/bvalidator/